# Is there an inductive definition of real numbers with a corresponding "proof by induction"?

Tags: real-analysis, induction, set-theory

I just read about inductively defining a set as follows :

> - Take a set of objects **U**.
> - Take a set of starting objects **B** ⊆ **U**.
> - Let **C** be the smallest subset of **U** that contains **B** and is closed under all operations on some class **F**.
>
>   > Any set **S** that contains **B** and is closed under all operations in **F** is called inductive.

For example , consider the set of natural numbers as :

> - **U** = **R** , **B** = {0} and **F** = {S} where S(x) = x+1

My Question is can we define positive Real Numbers as follows :

> **U** = **R** , **B** = [0 , 1) and **F** = {S} where S(x) = x+1

If so , can we prove property P(x) of positive real numbers inductively as follows :

> - P is true in interval [0,1).
> - If P(x) is true ,P(x+1) is also true.

Comment: Well, kinda? It's definitely not a single step induction, but you can transfinitely induct on the reals. So no, not exactly the properties you want, but similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you transfinitely induct, you lose any sense of the normal order on the reals. That may not be desirable.

Comment: When you "define" reals this way most of the work is swept under the rug in the initial set $[0 , 1)$. A proof of $P(x)$ for $x\in[0 , 1)$ will likely go through for all real $x$ without any induction. There is a more meaningful "induction" on reals, where you prove 1) $P(x_0)$; 2) If $P(x)$ then $P(x+h)$ for all small $h$; 3) If $P(x_n)$ and $x_n\to x$ then $P(x)$. Then $P(x)$ follows for all $x\geq x_0$, see [real induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1276691/152568).

Comment: @Conifold Is the definition correct ?

Comment: It isn't a definition since fractional reals are taken as a given. A meaningful definition has to start from something independently constructible, like integers or rationals.

Comment: There is a truly inductive definition that generates reals (and beyond) due to Conway, see [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number#Induction). But the induction will not correlate with the usual order on the reals.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/induction-on-real-numbers

Answer (score 1):

There is something analogue to the induction principle, called transfinite induction. It is not quite as intuitive as simple induction on $\omega$, but you make do with what you have. It works like this: let $P$ be a property, which you want to proof is true for all ordinal (or cardinal) numbers. You want to show that
1)-P(0) is true
2)-For all ordinals $a < b$, if $P(a)$ is true, $P(b)$ is true

Usually, the latter is divided in two stages, the successor ordinal and the limit ordinal: for the successor, you apply induction sort of in the classical way, whereas for the limit ordinal you have to rely on the fact that it is defined as $sup\{b|b > a\}$, and use 2)